# Increased cases of incorrect POS errors in Stanford Core NLP v4.0.0

Tags: stanford-nlp

Ive just tried out v4.0.0

Can anyone comment on the following issues?

1/ it makes lots of mistakes on the POS for the start of sentences

But the dependency parser is still looking correct.

2/ Parser often creates more 'dep' dependencies (which are effectively errors)

I tried to compare this to online demos to see if its the same

They always seem to be down now - but corenlp.run was showing same errors.

e.g.

Using:

```
edu/stanford/nlp/models/parser/nndep/english_UD.gz ... 
edu/stanford/nlp/models/pos-tagger/english-left3words-distsim.tagger
```

A/ POS errors

```
"He always updates the maps"

-> updates/NNS (root)
  -> He/PRP (nsubj)
  -> always/RB (advmod)
  -> maps/NNS (obj)
    -> the/DT (det)
```

B/ Seems to often treat a JJR as the root as a RBR
eg.

```
"the car is faster"
-> faster/RBR (root)
  -> car/NN (nsubj)
    -> the/DT (det)
  -> is/VBZ (cop)
```

Comment: Hi I can try to run a comparison between the 3.9.2 model and 4.0.0 model and see if I see any large scale differences. The ultimate issue we substantially altered the training data for 4.0.0. Our internal tests suggested the new model had comparable accuracy, but I can try to directly compare changes.

Comment: Also I restarted the demo.

Comment: Thanks. 
I get the same results in the corenlp demo. 
I had a lot of automated tests setup on the 3.9.2 - and Ive been correcting them for the 4.0.0 changes.  i.e. dobj -> dobj etc.

I notice that lots of the tests are now failing because of pos or dep issues.
Most of the tests are on short statement examples like above. 

And it seems 4.0.0 results in a lot more 'dep' than before.
It appears to be more sensitive now to non-perfect or uncommon statements/grammar

What the training data more formal english?

Comment: The extra training data is newswire text.